# ColdFusion - Session Variables - Losing Them

Tags: server, coldfusion, session-variables, windows-server-2016, coldfusion-2016

I have a session variable that is set to 60 days.
But it is dropping each day.

What I have been using for code has been working for years.  I have moved to a new virtual server.  And my CF Administrator settings seem to all be the same.  Could it be a Windows Server 2016 issue?  Using ColdFusion 2016 and Windows Server 2016.

As related this code has worked forever.  Still works in older server.  But now on new virtual server it will not work.  Thoughts?

At the login page. After successful login.

```
        <cfset session.allowin = "True">
        <cfset session.user_id = log.uid>
```

On the Application.cfm page.

```
        <cfapplication name="MyApp" clientmanagement="Yes"
            sessionmanagement="Yes"
            sessiontimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(61,0,0,0)#"
            applicationtimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(61,0,0,0)#">
```

Comment: Check the session timeout in CF Administrator.

Comment: I checked - the default is 20 hrs, which is the exact same as my older server settings.  And I never had issues.

Comment: And this is the note also:  These values specify the timeout period that ColdFusion uses if you do not specify an application-specific value in the cfapplication tag.

Comment: Just to clarify, the default value is 20 minutes, not 20 hours for session. I cannot think of any reason to have a session that lasts that long. Perhaps new security enhancements in 2016+ do not actually allow that to protect you.  I don't know at this point, Just speculating. Is the new VS behind different hardware than the rest? Could something in between be manipulating the session cookies?

Comment: Defaults : Application is 2 days, session is 20 mins.  But I am overriding both.  It is too keep the folks logged into the software. So they don't have to login all the time.  I do control some other software, for say example a 12hr shift etc.  But this one specifically is for booking drop in activity which occurs daily.  So the users just don't need to login all the time.  It is the biggest complaint I get lol.  Is the continual login.

Comment: Does it happen in different browsers? May not be the issue, but if "Secure cookies" are enabled in the CF Admin and the connections are plain http (not https), that could cause the behavior you described.

Comment: Are you using `jsessionid` cookies or just `CFID` + `CFTOKEN` cookies, and is that the same for both the old and new servers? As well as the 'secure' cookie flag that SOS mentioned if you are on plain http, you could also have a similar problem if you are framing your app from a 3rd party domain and you have not configured the samesite cookie attribute value to allow passing the session cookies through. Have a look in your browser console and check for errors in the console and warnings on the cookie http headers on the network tab.

Comment: Cookies are not being set. Its session being set.

Comment: But you understand that in order to tie an individual browser to a session on the server, CF sets session ID cookies for you, right? (assuming you're not passing tokens around in URL params like it's 1999); Is it just one particular session variable that you have a persistence problem with, or do any and all attempts at using session variables get lost prematurely?

Comment: I think I have figured it out.  The Virtual Server is a clone of another server that restarts itself evry day at 3am.  As the one site had some large loads. The easiiest fix was to restart the server.  So I will remove that on this server.  Obviously if the server reboots itself each day it would kill the variables.

Comment: UPDATE: I have remove the reboot task.  I shall see tomorrow if all is well.

Comment: Yes a daily restart would kill your session variables. Sounds like the server that originally needed daily restarts due to load, probably has code with memory leaks that need fixing.

Comment: Resolved - was server reboot.  My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my bad.  I had cloned a Virtual Server that rebooted every day at 2am.

So that reboot would clear all the session variable.

This is resolved now.

Thank you all for posting this and that, it led to good server setup reviews.